# Adobe reader files

Tags: 8.1, pdf

How can I export my files in adobe reader app to document folder. (For access from my laptop) I have a WP 8.1 on my Lumia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with the Adobe Reader atm. With Microsoft's PDF Reader app you can at least upload your documents on OneDrive - but not save it to your documents folder unfortunately.